# Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install. ERROR

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart, cocoapods

i get this Error, when trying to run my app from android studio IDE.

[Error mesasge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sye23.png)

I can run it from my terminal, with `flutter run`, it works all fine. But my IDE fails. And i have cocoapods, and it works finde too.
I am running this on a old mac, with Catalina 10.15.7.

**UPDATE**
I did not found a solution, but using Visual Studio Code, did the job, now i can run my app on IOS again. I think its a Android Studio problem.

Comment: You installed cocoapods by brew?

Comment: @Jackie Jensen It is android studio new version error. You need to run your code in visual studio and once run in visual studio its perfect work in Android studio.

Comment: Yes, and my cocoapods works fine anywhere else.

But visual studio code works.

Answer (score 0):

I face this same issue with new upgrade of Android Studio Bumblebee in new M1 Mac Chip...
So I solve this issue via this...

1. Check you `gem list` to find the all version of cocoapods
2. Uninstall your Cocoapod: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

3.Then Install it again : `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

close android Studio
open terminal

run `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv`

run Android Studio from dock